# How create method for get the child (QWebEngineView) of th curent view tab (QTabWidget)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget, qwebengineview

I'm trying to make some project with QTabWidget (a litle browser and a text editor with multiple tab like notepad++) but I'm stuck in 2 project when I try to edit a value of widget (QWebEngine or QTextEdit) inside of QTabWidget. This is the code for the litle browser project:

fp.h :

```
#ifndef FP_H
#define FP_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class fp; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class fp : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    fp(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~fp();

public slots:
    void newtab();
    void deltab();
    void newpage();
    QWebEngineView *ap();
    int cui();
private:
    Ui::fp *ui;
    QWebEngineView *webnav;

};
#endif // FP_H
```

fp.cpp

```
#include "fp.h"
#include "ui_fp.h"

fp::fp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::fp)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->in_url->setText("https://google.com");

}

fp::~fp()
{
    delete ui;
}

void fp::newtab()
{
QWebEngineView *webnav = new QWebEngineView;
webnav->load(QUrl("https://google.com"));
webnav->setObjectName("webnav");
ui->in_url->setText("https://google.com");
ui->onglet->addTab(webnav,"Home");
}
int fp::cui()
{
    return ui->onglet->currentIndex();
}
QWebEngineView *fp::ap()
{
    return ui->onglet->currentWidget()->findChild<QWebEngineView *>("webnav");
}
void fp::deltab()
{
    ui->onglet->removeTab(cui());
}

void fp::newpage()
{
    QString use_url = ui->in_url->text();
    ap()->load(use_url);
}
```

and there what look like the .ui
[Image of .ui in Qdesigner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i67yc.png)

I try to make work the method "ap" it should return the QWebEngineView child of current viewed tab but when I call the slots "newpage" (it currently using "ap" method) it just crash the application. This slot is trigered when I enter a new URL in the QLineEdit in .ui
(before that I create a new tab whit a QWebEngineView inside whit the slot "newtab" )

```
void fp::newtab()
{
QWebEngineView *webnav = new QWebEngineView;
webnav->load(QUrl("https://google.com"));
webnav->setObjectName("webnav");
ui->in_url->setText("https://google.com");
ui->onglet->addTab(webnav,"Home");
}
```

So what wrong whit that line it the good method for get child widget of a QTabWidget? If it the good method what should be modified to make it work?

```
QWebEngineView *fp::ap()
{
    return ui->onglet->currentWidget()->findChild<QWebEngineView *>("webnav");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```cpp
QWebEngineView *view = qobject_cast<QWebEngineView *>(
    this->ui->onglet->widget(0)
);
```

> **Note** to put above somewhere in `fp`'s methods (where you need the reference).
>
> I could use `ui->onglet->currentWidget()`, but the difference is, that will not work once you have multiple tabs.

Comment: Thank you, really i pass the last 3 day to search a way to do this. that work perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @Bestgamer29 If this was helpful, consider accepting and/or upvoting (there should be a tick-mark button somewhere).